# Reducing the Frame-Rate of a Network Video Stream with FFMPEG

Tags: c, ffmpeg, frame-rate, libavcodec, libavformat

I have a *network* video stream that I am decoding with the ffmpeg C library.
I'd like to reduce the *maximal* frame rate to some maximum, say 15 fps.
I used the filter [`fps=fps=15`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps), but even on a 25 fps video stream this caused frame duplication. I presume this was due to network delays.

Is there some way to reduce the *maximal* frame-rate but avoid frame duplication and just get delays instead?
If not, is there a way to identify if a decoded frame is one of the duplicates?

Comment: Please see the [ffmpeg] wiki tag's excerpt.

Comment: As I said,  I am decoding with the ffmpeg C library. I am not using the command line tool.